# How do I make a Chrome App window above other windows of the same app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Chrome App, and it talks to some hardware and displays some information to the user. I want it to have two windows, and some control over the z-order of them.

## Starting with the content

The main one (I call it the "main" window) is always open, although it can be minimized. It's fairly large (left half of a laptop to mid-size desktop screen-ish), and displays some fairly technical information (which isn't really important here).

The user can press a button and open another window (the "meter" window) which is small (on the order of 100px by 100px) and boils down the information to a 'do stuff' button, and a meter that ranges from 0 to 100.

## The desired behavior

What I want is for the meter window to always be on top of the main window. That's the only special behavior that I want from the meter window with regards to z-order.

### Something that isn't what I want

What I don't want is for the meter window to be always on top of everything. This is what I get with Chrome's `alwaysOnTop`.

### One possibility that leads to another problem.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415555/how-do-i-make-an-air-nativewindow-always-in-front-of-just-the-app-but-not-in-fr)'s another question which is almost kinda the same as mine but in a different framework (Adobe AIR) and actually not that similar at all. But it does give me the idea to make the meter window topmost if and only if there are no other windows covering either window. That might not work *exactly* the way I want, but it would be close(r).

Unfortunately, that would require me to try to be aware of all the other windows in the system which would be fairly intrusive, and I'm not aware of a way to do that anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can fake this somewhat by listening to `onBoundsChanged` of the main window, and then toggling `alwaysOnTop` for the meter window on and then off again.

```
firstWindow.onBoundsChanged.addListener(function() {
    secondWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    secondWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
});
```

This isn't a perfect solution and might not work on all environments. Another approach would be to do something like the [windows](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/windows) sample, which forces the second window to stay on the right of the first window.

```
firstWindow.onBoundsChanged.addListener(function() {
    var bounds = firstWindow.outerBounds;
    secondWindow.outerBounds.left = bounds.left + bounds.width + 5;
});
```